# Is 'transfer' in this context correct?

Tags: word-request

Consider this expression

> Can you please **transfer** the sugar of this packet in that jar.
>
> I spilled some corn flakes when I was **transferring** them to a jar.

Is it ok using transfer in this context? If not what word should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Transfer* seems like too formal a word to use when talking about corn flakes and sugar. I'd reserve *transfer* for *information*, *data*, or perhaps ownership of an automobile:

> You can't just give them your car, you need to transfer the title.

As for which word to use instead, I'd probably say *put*, but that requires a preposition change:

> Can you please **put** the sugar that's in this packet *into* that jar?
>
> I spilled some corn flakes while I was **putting** them *in* a jar.

NOAD defines *put* as:

> move to or place in a particular position, or to cause (someone or something) to go to a particular place and remain there for a time

(The word has other meanings as well, but that's the relevant definition in this context.)

Relevant [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=put+in+a+jar%2Ctransfer+to+a+jar&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)? You can find "transfer to a jar" in literature, but its usage seems to be pretty much confined to cook books, where more formal kitchen language is used.

Answer (score -1):

I would phrase this as:

> Can you please transfer the sugar from this packet and into that jar.

I don't have a problem with the use of transfer in this case...

> I spilled some corn flakes when I was transferring them to a jar.

Is fine.